A pattern in factorization of certrain symmetric polynomials made of sums of squares and products
Secondary-school pupils may learn things like
$$(a+b-c)^2 = a^2+b^2+c^2 +2ab - 2ac - 2bc$$
and that no choice of plus versus minus can give us
$$
(\pm a\pm b\pm c)^2 = a^2+b^2+c^2 - 2ab - 2ac - 2bc,
$$
with only minus signs on the product terms and only plus signs on the square terms. But then
\begin{align}
& 2a^2b^2 + 2a^2c^2 + 2b^2c^2 -a^4 - b^4 - c^4 \\[5pt]
= {} & (a+b+c)(a+b-c)(b+c-a)(c+a-b),
\end{align}
with only plus signs for the product terms and only minus signs for the square terms.
By taking higher powers of the variables, can we factor
$$
\pm\sum_{a\,\in\,A} a^{2n} \mp \sum_{a,b\,\in\,A} 2a^nb^n 
$$
as a product of first-degree polynomials, for larger sets $A$ of variables? Does $n$ grow as the number of variables grows?
Appendix (added later) As I mentioned in comments what prompted this question was an idea that probably doesn't make much sense, but it's about whether this may have some connection with certain trigonometric identities. This image shows one special case. 

I'm pretty sure that if $A$ has at least four elements then the given sum is irreducible for all positive integers $n$ when the two signs are different.

I just ran it on magma - when $|A|=4$, it's irreducible for $1\leqslant n \leqslant 500$.

$$
\begin{align}
\text{If } & \sum_i\theta_i=\pi \text{ then} \
& \sum_i \sin^2\theta_i - 2\sum_{i,,j,:,i,\ne,j}\left( \sin\theta_i\sin\theta_j \prod_{k,:,i,\ne,k,\ne,j} \cos\theta_k \right) \ {} \
& + 4\sum_{\text{distinct } i ,, j,,k,,\ell} \left( \sin\theta_i \sin\theta_j\sin\theta_k\sin\theta_\ell
\prod_{m,:, m,\notin,{,i,,j,,k,,\ell,}} \cos\theta_m \right) \ {} \ &- 6\sum_\text{etc.} \cdots\cdots + 8\sum_\text{etc.} \cdots\cdots - 10 \sum_\text{etc.} \cdots\cdots + \cdots\cdots =0.
\end{align}
$$

The trigonometric identity above is what made me think of this. Every few months I look at this and wonder whether I can find some geometric meaning in it.

Seems like you are considering $n$-fold etale covers of a certain quadric hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^{|A|}$, which are also in $\mathbb{P}^{|A|}$. Such a cover would be good from your perspective, if it has degree $1$ (and hence looks like a union of hyperplanes). In this case you may want to look at things like the degree of the canonical bundle, and how this invariant transforms along such covers.

I just realized the factor of $2$ in the second term in the trigonometric identity above belongs there only if $ \displaystyle \sum_{i,,j , :, i,\ne,j} $ is taken to mean a sum over all sets ${,i,,j,}$ of two indices rather than over all ordered pairs $(i,,j)$ of indices.
